Vite Vanilla Js build is showing blank page in live server
I installed the latest Vite template using Vite Official Docs.
I am using the Vanilla JS,
The problem is that when I create a build by using npm run build and open it with a live server.
It will show me a blank page...
Showing Console Errors

But if I do npm run preview or npm run dev it shows me the web content fine.
I am trying to deploy the project but the build of the Vanilla Js Vite is showing a Blank Page
